# Calculate percentage in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I'm looking to calculate the uptime of my servers under Azure Application Insight via Kusto. So, I'm planning to create a query to pull Successful requests and other query for failed requests and later on I want to calculate the percentage of it. So, that I can get a value like 99.89% or 97% availability of my app in the selected time.

Comment: So you have read the docs, tried some queries and you're stuck? Can you post you attempt so we have something to work on?

Comment: **See Also**: [add column to show percentages of total](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65514010/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the following examples could give you a direction:

```
let failures = ... query that returns all failed requests ...;
let successes = ... query that returns all successful requests ...;
let failure_count = toscalar(failures | count);
let success_count = toscalar(successes | count);
print success_rate = strcat(round(100.0 * success_count / (success_count + failure_count), 2), "%")
```

```
datatable(status:string, dt:datetime)
[
    "success", datetime(2020-12-01 21:52:50),
    "failure", datetime(2020-12-01 21:52:54),
    "success", datetime(2020-12-01 21:53:01),
    "success", datetime(2020-12-01 21:53:09),
    "success", datetime(2020-12-01 21:53:13),
    "success", datetime(2020-12-01 21:53:17),
    "success", datetime(2020-12-01 21:53:25),
    "failure", datetime(2020-12-01 21:53:33)
]
| summarize success_rate = strcat(round(100.0 * countif(status == "success") / count(), 2), "%")
```

this returns a single table with a single column named `success_rate`, with a single record that has the value `75%`

Comment: Thanks Yoni, but I'm not able to figure it out that how I can add all the failed and successful calls in the array [ ] and calculate from there.

Comment: I've added another example which may be helpful - if not, please follow the advice in the other comment to your original post: `...Can you post your attempt so we have something to work on?`

Comment: Your above solution worked, Thank You Yoni.