# Kusto | add column to show percentages of total

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have seen several other questions similar to this but each is slightly different and none of them provide an answer I was able to adapt to my situation. I have a table like this:

```
let T = 
    datatable(Val1:string, Val2:string, Val3:bool)
    [
        '', 'false', 'false',
        'Yes', 'false', 'true',
        'No', 'false', 'false',
        'Yes', 'false', 'false'
    ]
;
```

I want to only get results where Val3 is false, summarize count by Val1 & Val2, then **extend a column to show the percentage of the whole** on each row. I have tried doing this:

```
T
| where Val3 == "false"
| summarize Count = count() by Val1, Val2
| let Total = sum(Count)
| extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Count/Total, 0)
```

Which throws an error `"A recognition error occurred. Token: let"` And I've tried many variations such as this:

```
T
| where Val3 == "false"
| summarize Count = count() by Val1, Val2
| extend Total = sum(Count)
| extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Count/Total, 0)
```

Which throws an error `"Function 'sum' cannot be invoked in current context"`. If I change `extend Total` to `summarize Total` then that line works, but it throws an error about not recognizing Count on the next line. If I add Count on the summarize line like this:

```
| summarize Total = sum(Count), Count
```

Then I get an error `"Non valid aggregation function is used after summarize"`.
This is the output I'm going for:

[image: expected results]

It seems like this is a lot more difficult than it should be. What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can calculate the percentage using a sub-query to get the total, passed into `toscalar()`. In the examples below, I've also used the `as` operator.

- `toscalar()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction
- `as` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/asoperator

```
datatable(Val1:string, Val2:string, Val3:bool)
[
    '', 'false', 'false',
    'Yes', 'false', 'true',
    'No', 'false', 'false',
    'Yes', 'false', 'false'
]
| where Val3 == "false"
| as T
| summarize Count = count() by Val1, Val2
| extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Count / toscalar(T | count), 2)
```

or, following the same concept - here's an alternative:

```
datatable(Val1:string, Val2:string, Val3:bool)
[
    '', 'false', 'false',
    'Yes', 'false', 'true',
    'No', 'false', 'false',
    'Yes', 'false', 'false'
]
| where Val3 == "false"
| summarize Count = count() by Val1, Val2
| as T
| extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Count / toscalar(T | summarize sum(Count)), 2)
```